# Función con RxJS y combineLatest a veces funciona y a veces no

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Si llamo a esta función varias veces siendo los valores de los observables obs1 y obs2 los mismos cada vez, el array devuelto no siempre es igual.

```
getProductosUnicos(obs1: Observable<any>, obs2: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    return combineLatest([obs1, obs2])
    .pipe(
      map(([prod1, prod2]) => {
          return prod1.find((prod: any) => prod1.NombreProducto === prod2)
      }),
      toArray(),
      tap( a => console.log(a.length))
    )
}
```

Lo que intento obtener son los objetos de obs1 cuyos NombreProducto coincidan con los strings que vienen de obs2.

Comment: Hola! antes de colaborarte quisiera ver el contexto de esa funcion. 
Como llegan esos Observables, vienen de un http Request o los generas con un  From() u of()... creeria que lo que necesitas es usar un forkJoin() que espere a que ambos observables se completen y ahi si ejecutar tu find()

Comment: He probado con forkJoin() pero solo devuelve un registro. La función está pensada para funcionar con distintos observables pero en origen vienen todos de un http Request.